# How can I get the phone number claim to be returned in the token for phone sign-up/sign-in

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

How can I get the phone number claim to be returned in the token for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-authentication-user-flows

I tried adding a custom user attribute as seen below, but it is not an ideal option as two phone number request fields are then returned to the customer.
Only the first field is required and the phone number claim should be returned.
[custom user attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZzmS.png)

Answer (score 0):

> You can get the phone number claim to be returned in the token for
> phone sign-up/sign-in using **custom policy**.

In my case, I deployed custom policy starter pack to my B2C tenant by enabling below options in **[IEF Setup App](https://b2ciefsetupapp.azurewebsites.net/)** page:

[image]

After deploying the starter pack, you can find custom policy named `B2C_1A_SIGNUPORSIGNINWITHPHONE` and run like below:

[image]

When you click on **`Run now`** option, new window will be opened with **login** screen:

[image]

Clicking on `Sign up now` option took me to below screen where it asked to enter **phone number** :

[image]

After entering the above details, it asked me to provide **recovery email** like this:

[image]

Clicking on `Create` button redirected with **phone number** claim in the token as below:

[image]

**Sample Relying party file**:

```xml
  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignInWithPhone" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.phoneNumber" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
```